# TypeError: Unable to change AppName in PySpark (Google Colab)

Tags: python, pyspark, google-colaboratory

I have recently started to learn pyspark and was trying to change my appName, which is 'us-counties' by default. I used the code below to change my appName but the output does not change. Help will be appreciated. Is this a collaboratory problem, and I should switch to Jupyter?

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('covid19')

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf = conf)

sc
```

Comment: I've just tested it on Google Colab and it's applying the new AppName. Did you create the Context/Session before with another name? If the session/context already exists, you are just getting the existing one.

Comment: @KevinBarranco No i don't think that is the case. I had only one line of code before this that was to use pd.read_csv. I switched to Jupyter, and it works somehow.

Comment: *"..., which is 'us-counties' by default"* -- do you mean there's a spark context already running on your colab notebook? if that's the case, you'd have to stop that and create a new context with the new name.